# What is the use of 'MessagesApi` in play framework

Tags: playframework

I have seen code where `MessageApi` is injected in a controller but is not used.

```
class Application @Inject() (
  val messagesApi: MessagesApi, 
  val env:Environment[User,CookieAuthenticator],//change to JWT?
  socialProviderRegistry: SocialProviderRegistry) extends Silhouette[User,CookieAuthenticator] {

  //anyone could access the home page
  def index = UserAwareAction.async { implicit request =>
    Future.successful(Ok(views.html.index(request.identity, request.authenticator.map(_.loginInfo))))
  }

  //only logged in users could access profile page.
  def profile = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.profile(request.identity, request.authenticator.loginInfo, socialProviderRegistry))
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of `MessageApi`? I thought is was used in internationalization but then I saw another class `Message` which I have seen been used to get values of messages stored in different language files eg. messages.fr and being used as `Messages("index.logged")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use key and lang from request to load i18n conf from message.xxx
from conf folder. It will turn out to be a string if find value by key else it will just return raw key.

```
class ExampleController (cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def example(): Action[Request] = Action.async(parse.json[Request]) { implicit request =>
    Accepted(messagesApi("data.processed")(request.lang))
  }
}
```

If your request lang is "en"
Add code as follow to message.en

```
data.processed = Ok!
```

You can find detail in document
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N